# How can you configure Chrome to open new browser instances in new windows rather than in a tab?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs

I want to create new Chrome windows (no tabs) from outside of Chrome, e.g. by running Chrome.exe multiple times.  How can I do this so as to get a single Chrome window?  The default result is to create new tabs in the existing window which requires me to drag and drop the tag to create a new window.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is this for a program that opens a browser link or for within the browser?

Comment: Interesting...everytime I execute Chrome.exe, it causes a new window with a single tab to appear, without affecting the existing instance(s) in any way.

Comment: actually I wanted to look for the inverse of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per this:

- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26728

using `--new-window` should work.

Comment: usage: `chrome --new-window superuser.com`

Comment: This works perfectly.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked!

Answer (score 3):

From a commandline, you can create new windows from URLS by running `chrome.exe --new-window <url>`.

If you're trying to accomplish something else you can always fall back to IE6+Chrome Frame ;-).