# How do I make Chrome open chrome://newtab in an existing window?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs

I am trying to create a shortcut for XLaunchpad and WinLaunch so that I can get a "new tab" (which contains the shortcuts to apps, etc.) to appear.  Not about:blank or a URL.

However when I use

```
chrome chrome://newtab
```

It keeps on opening a new window.

It is sort of the inverse of [How can you configure Chrome to open new browser instances in new windows rather than in a tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/213460/how-can-you-configure-chrome-to-open-new-browser-instances-in-new-windows-rather)

Comment: Thanks for the comments below. I've edited your question to make it clearer for others to respond to. Please look at the changes to make sure I got it correct.

Answer (score 4):

http://

Just a blank http:// opens a new tab in chrome. This is the StackExchange syntax but its not displaying as a hyperlink:

`[http://](http://)`

Comment: Or, in relation to the actual question, use `chrome http://somewebsite.com` instead of the `chrome://` prefix.

Comment: This still opens up the "new tab" in a new window.  So this is not correct.

Comment: @lsxek I am trying to get the "new tab" (which has the apps etc) showing up.

Comment: actually a blank http:// on the omnibar also redirects to a google search for "http://" so this answer is just wrong.

Comment: There's a [related question](http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chrome/PmCbBZ06gBA/discussion) on the Chrome forums, but it hasn't been answered yet. Looking at the [available CL switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) for Chrome, it looks like this ability is not available yet.

Answer (score 1):

For me, running something like

```
start chrome https://google.com
```

opens a page in a new tab, but running

```
start chrome http://
```

(as suggested by the other answer) opens a *new window*. Perhaps it worked in the past?

As an ugly workaround, I save the following script as **newtab.bat**, and run the script from my shortcut key instead of running chrome directly:

```vb
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off

SET SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
SET KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe"
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /ve') DO SET Chrome=%%B

"%Chrome%" https://google.com
%SendKeys% "^t^+{TAB}^w"

goto :EOF
@end

// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Explanation:

1. Get the chrome executable path from the Windows registry
2. Run chrome, opening `https://google.com` in a new tab (brings chrome into focus)
3. SendKeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

   This is the shortcut for opening a new tab.
4. SendKeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

   This shortcut switches back one tab (to google, which we just opened).
5. SendKeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

   This shortcut closes the current tab (the google tab).

(Did I mention it was an ugly workaround?)

The result is the `chrome://newtab` page opened in an existing chrome window (or a new window if none were open on the current desktop). I tried a lot of other variations of command line arguments and shortcuts, but I just couldn't find a better way from outside of chrome to open the new tab page in an *existing* window.

The SendKeys parts are modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050135/6038111).